# Can't display list of upcoming events google calendar v3

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get the list of upcoming events from a google calendar using their v3 api. I have used the following code

```
            var eventName = '';
            var today =  new Date();
            var iso  = encodeURI(ISODateString(today));
            var gclaData = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/rkmfiji.org_lrt0ou2o2prjbrfa3f0tuhqopk@group.calendar.google.com/events?singleEvents=true&maxResults=3&timeMin='+iso+'&key=AIzaSyCP4j-U4GzJri3zaADP4FM1aVsIJ0Mqhj4';

            jQuery.getJSON(gclaData,function(data){
              for(var i=0;i<data.items.length;i++){
                var eventrow='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3">'
                var eventdate = new Date(data.items[i].start.dateTime);
                eventrow+='<h4 class="eventheader">'+months[eventdate.getMonth()]+'</h4><h3 class="eventheader">'+eventdate.getDate()+'</h3></div>'
                eventrow+='<div class="col-md-9"><h5 class="header blogtitle">'+data.items[i].summary+'</h5><p>'+data.items[i].description+'</p>'
                eventrow+='<a href="'+data.items[i].htmlLink+'" target="_blank">More Details & Attend</a>'
                eventrow+='<div class="spacer40"</div></div></div>'
                jQuery('.gcal').append(eventrow);
              }
              if(!data.items.length) jQuery('.gcal').append('<h3 class="header">No Upcoming Events</h3>');
            });
```

With the code above, I only get upcoming **recurring** events. If I remove the singleEvents = true, I get events in the past. I have tried many different variations but never what I want, a list of upcoming recurring and non-recurring events (so starting from today).

Does anybody see anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found the solution. Google will display the whole list of recurring events even if one of the instances of the recurring event happens after a one off event. Because my recurring event has no end, my one off event could never be displayed. To solve this problem, add a

```
&orderBy = startTime
```

to the query